# How can I trigger function in django while reading it's output without impacting that functions execution time?

Tags: python, django, multithreading, electron

I've been trying to find a solution to my issue for some time now, but I haven't come across anything that seems intuitive enough that it seems like the "right" solution.

I'm building an electron app that uses django as the backend. The backend is responsible for running some long processes that are time critical. For example, I have a loop that continuously takes data for about 5 seconds. When I run that function standalone, it takes a data point about every 10 ms, however, when I run it through django it takes a data point anywhere from 10 ms to 70 ms or even longer. This makes sense to me intuitively because django is sharing thread time to keep responding to the frontend. However, this is unacceptable for my application.

The delays seem to be related to returning data to the frontend. Basically, there's a static variable in the view class that's a container for the result data, then the measurement is triggered from the front end  and the measurement populates that static variable with data. When the measurement is running, the front end queries django once a second for updated data so it can plot it for the user to track progress.

I first tried using `threading.Thread` to create a new thread to run the measurement. This thread gets triggered by the django view, but that doesn't fix the issue. Ok, maybe this makes sense too because the thread is still sharing processing time with the main thread?

The next step seems to be creating an entirely new subprocess. However, I'd still like to be passing data back to the front end while the script runs, so short of dropping a file, I don't know how to do that.

Is there an officially supported way to run a function through django who's execution time won't be impacted by the fact that it's being triggered from django?

Comment: Python doesn't run threads of execution in parallel because of the Global Interpreter Lock -  only one thread runs at a time and the rest are blocked. I would normally suggest something like a ProcessPoolExecutor if you need truly parallel execution, or perhaps a full fledged task queue like Celery; but given the performance you're looking for, it's probably worth your time to write it as a C extension (C will have the performance characteristics you want, and C extensions are not affected by the GIL)

Comment: @Blackhawk For this specific implementation, that would be quite difficult to do because I'm interested in treating almost the entire application in this way. Since it's an electron app, we're trying to keep the frontend as light as possible and just do all processing on the backend. This specific time critical component I'm working with would also be hard to extract to C because it leverages third party libraries for instrument control. It would be a lot of work to move all that into C.